# NSJSON how to parse

Tags: ios, json, ios5, viewdidload, nsjsonserialization

I am having issues getting the json format by a specific "". I can see that it is a dictionary so am I turning the dictionary into an array wrong? I am trying to pull the records that "isReserevble=true" and then display the "begin" with just the time in the table view cells based on the user selection from a UIDatepicker.
The json is coming through with NSlog but I am not able to figure this out. Thanks

It looks like I hae an array of dictionaries. Would I still use the same methods?

here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                        kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    });

}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data

NSError* error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray* myslots =[json objectForKey:@"slots"];
NSLog(@"allslots: %@", myslots);


  NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *slots in json){
    NSLog(@"isReservable = %@",[myslots objectForKey:@"isReservable"]);
    if ([[myslots objectForKey:@"isReservable"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"begin = %@",[myslots objectForKey:@"begin"]);
        [datesArray addObject:[myslots objectForKey:@"begin"]];
        NSLog(@"slots array count = %d",[datesArray count]);
    }

}
NSLog(@"This is the begin: %@", datesArray);

}
```

Here is my result of NSLog all slots:

```
2012-08-29 11:54:26.531 GBSB[1137:15b03] allslots: {
    "2012-08-29 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" =     (
                {
            begin = "2012-08-29 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
            end = "2012-08-29 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
            isPending = 0;
            isReservable = 0;
            isReserved = 0;
            label = "&nbsp;";
            span = 1;
        },
                {
            begin = "2012-08-29 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
            end = "2012-08-29 08:15:00 America/Los_Angeles";
            isPending = 0;
            isReservable = 1;
            isReserved = 0;
            label = "&nbsp;";
            span = 1;
        }
    );
}
```

Ok: Here is now what I am getting

```
2012-08-30 09:28:30.812 GBSB[835:15b03] its a dictionary
2012-08-30 09:28:30.812 GBSB[835:15b03] isReservable = (null)
2012-08-30 09:28:30.812 GBSB[835:15b03] isReservable = (null)
2012-08-30 09:28:30.812 GBSB[835:15b03] isReservable = (null)
2012-08-30 09:28:30.813 GBSB[835:15b03] This is the begin: (
)
```

Comment: is `json` the ivar associated with the property `json`? You use both, for no apparent reason.

Comment: I am new at this so I might of made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is - again - helpful. Try to interpret it:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81e1c80
```

That means, you sent the `objectForKey:` message to the JSON *string* object instead of the *parsed NSDictionary* object, that's what's wrong.

Comment: Are you still getting this error (which you deleted in your update)? If you are, then H2CO3 is right. If you still are getting this error, json is a string, like he said. That needs to be fixed first. Can you print out the contents of json in the debugger? Use po json. Post the results in your question (not as a comment) to get the benefit of question formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It's this bit that's causing you problems :

```
for (NSDictionary *tempDict in self.json) {
    [datesArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"slots"]];
}
```

You think you're asking for the `"slots"` property of your JSON but you're not, you're asking for the `"slots"` property of *each child dictionary* in your JSON.

Try just this instead :

```
[datesArray addObject:[self.json objectForKey:@"slots"]];
```

Comment: change self.json from nsarray to dictionary and then I get 
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"slots"];    No visible @interface for 'NSDic'...

Comment: I didn't say change self.json from NSArray to NSDictionary - why would you do that, it's an array! Have you tried what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: a little change. My json is now Dictionary with keys that have array of dictionaries. Thanks for the help. I posted a different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204006/how-to-parse-dictionary-with-keys-that-have-array-of-dictionaries