# How to parse Dictionary with keys that have array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, nsarray, nsjsonserialization

UPDATE-8/31/12- So now I would need to go through the Array of Dictionaries based on "isReservable" = 1 and then display the "begin". I am just trying to get the contents of the array of each dictionary and I can go from there (for now). Below is what I have tried. Thanks to everyone for the help I am learning more everyday.

json from php page

```
{
"slots": {
    "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles": [
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-30 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-30 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-30 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-30 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": false,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-30 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": false,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": false,
            "isReserved": true,
            "label": "Thomas Kroom",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 5
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        }
    ],
    "2012-09-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles": [
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-08-31 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": false,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-08-31 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": false,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 10:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 10:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 11:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 11:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 11:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 11:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 12:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 12:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        },
        {
            "isPending": false,
            "isReservable": true,
            "isReserved": false,
            "label": "&nbsp;",
            "begin": "2012-09-01 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "end": "2012-09-01 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
            "span": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have so far

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data

    NSError* error;
    //NSLog(@"string is %@", responseData);

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSDictionary* myslots =[json objectForKey:@"slots"];
NSLog(@"allslots: %@", myslots);
//for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    //NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
    //NSLog(@"These are all the keys: %@", slotKey);
    NSArray *keys = [myslots allKeys];
```

Update- This is how I am getting it to work:

```
for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
        NSArray *tests = [myslots objectForKey:slotKey];
    for (NSDictionary *myDict in tests){
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDict objectForKey:@"begin"]); 
    }
    }
```

Now I just need to change it to say if "isReservable" = true then display "begin"

Comment: It may help to post a sample JSON response because I am having trouble understanding the layout of your NSDictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like myslots is an NSDictionary, not an NSArray ... to iterate through all it's keys, change

```
for (NSDictionary *slots in myslots) {
    // code
}
```

for

```
for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
    // code
}
```

Comment: I am trying to pull the records that "isReserevble=1" and then display the "begin" with just the time in the table view cells, with this is just gives me the "2012-08-30 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" and "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"

Comment: I am trying to get the details inside these though

Answer (score 0):

myslots is a dictionary. it seems that the first key "2012-08-30 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" is the one associated with the array you are looking for. I would recommend to restructure your data to have an actual, static key as the key to access the values inside the dictionary.